# App running crash with this error: could not find class external jar Android

Tags: java, android, jar, external

I add an external jar to libs folder, and i can see this methods from the code and no error appears. When i compile the app launch no problem but when i press the botton that use the method of the external jar the app crash, this is the Logcat:

```
05-15 13:37:49.782: E/dalvikvm(17475): Could not find class 'es.jerogaren.funciones.aleatorio1', referenced from method com.example.ejemplo.FullscreenActivity$5.onClick
05-15 13:37:49.782: W/dalvikvm(17475): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 1034 (Les/jerogaren/funciones/aleatorio1;) in Lcom/example/ejemplo/FullscreenActivity$5;
05-15 13:37:49.782: D/dalvikvm(17475): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x0007
05-15 13:37:49.782: D/dalvikvm(17475): DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0x2125 at 0x09 in Lcom/example/ejemplo/FullscreenActivity$5;.onClick
05-15 13:37:49.812: I/Adreno-EGL(17475): <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:320>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM Build: I0404c4692afb8623f95c43aeb6d5e13ed4b30ddbDate: 11/06/13
05-15 13:37:49.842: D/OpenGLRenderer(17475): Enabling debug mode 0
05-15 13:37:51.624: W/dalvikvm(17475): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x415e4ba8)
05-15 13:37:51.634: E/AndroidRuntime(17475): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-15 13:37:51.634: E/AndroidRuntime(17475): Process: com.example.ejemplo, PID: 17475
05-15 13:37:51.634: E/AndroidRuntime(17475): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: es.jerogaren.funciones.aleatorio1
05-15 13:37:51.634: E/AndroidRuntime(17475):    at com.example.ejemplo.FullscreenActivity$5.onClick(FullscreenActivity.java:137)
05-15 13:37:51.634: E/AndroidRuntime(17475):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
05-15 13:37:51.634: E/AndroidRuntime(17475):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
05-15 13:37:51.634: E/AndroidRuntime(17475):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
05-15 13:37:51.634: E/AndroidRuntime(17475):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
05-15 13:37:51.634: E/AndroidRuntime(17475):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
05-15 13:37:51.634: E/AndroidRuntime(17475):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-15 13:37:51.634: E/AndroidRuntime(17475):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
05-15 13:37:51.634: E/AndroidRuntime(17475):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
```

I am working with windows 8 and Nexus 4,

Is there something that i am doing wrong?

Comment: Have you checked the Order and Exports tab? Have a look at [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/WWzwm.png) and make sure that your jars are ticked.

Comment: Check the order and select the checkbox for teh same..android libraries should come before other external libraries

Comment: Yes, the lib appears at libraries--> Android Private Libraries and in Order and Exports tabs are checked both Android Private Libraries and Android Dependencies

Comment: The order are: the first Android Libraries (Android Dependencies) the last Android Private Libraries.

Comment: I have edited the title to not be so generic